# Evaluate $\int {2x\over x^2-1}dx$

Tags: integration

My friend evaluated this before he went to bed: $$\int {2x\over x^2-1}dx$$

The answer was $\log(x^2-1)$.

I just can't figure out how that works. I know that $\int \frac1x dx = \log|x|$, so what just happened to $2x$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $\quad\quad u  = \;x^2 - 1.\quad$ (Use "$\;u$-substitution.")

Then $\;\;\; du = 2x \;\;dx$.

$($Recall, we need to replace $\;2x\;dx\;$ with $\;du\;$ to integrate in terms of $u.)$

This gives us...

$$\int \frac{2x \;dx}{x^2 - 1} \quad=\quad \int \frac{du}{u} \quad= \quad\int \frac{1}{u} du \;\;= \;\;\;?$$

From what you stated in your question, I think you can go from here?

Comment: Ah thanks! You edited the ans. the way i kept thinking lol

Comment: You're welcome, Kishan!

Comment: (+1) what a good word. $u-$ substitution. I didn't see this.

Answer (score 13):

$$\int\frac{2x}{x^2-1}dx=\int\frac{(x+1)+(x-1)}{x^2-1^2}dx=$$

$$=\int\frac{(x+1)+(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}dx=\int\left(\frac{x+1}{(x+1)(x-1)}+\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-1)}\right)dx=$$

$$=\int\left(\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x+1}\right)dx=\int\left(\frac1{x-1}\right)dx+\int\left(\frac1{x+1}\right)dx=$$
$$=\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)+C=\ln(x-1)(x+1)+C=\ln(x^2-1)+C$$

Comment: I love the elementary way. I always do as you, think like you. It is more effective than complicated ones. +1

Answer (score 7):

$\frac{2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x+1)+(x-1)}{x^2-1}=\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x+1}$

---

Alternatively, using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html), let $\frac{2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x+1)+(x-1)}{x^2-1}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x-1}$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

So, $2x=(A+B)x+B-A$

Comparing the constant terms in either of the identity, $B-A=0\implies A=B$

Comparing the coefficients of $x,A+B=2\implies A=B=1$

So, $\frac{2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x+1)+(x-1)}{x^2-1}=\frac 1{x+1}+\frac 1{x-1}$

Comment: +1 just for showing there are multiple ways to solve problems, but I think you should have factored $x^2 - 1$ and completed the re-combining of the logs to be explicit.

Comment: @half-integerfan, could you please have a look into the edited answer?

Comment: Well, by writing $(x+1) + (x-1)$ for $2x$ you've given away the answer.  If you just start with A and B then that shows that the solution can be arrived at even if you can't do that trick "by inspection".  I would have also explicitly shown the $\frac{A(x-1) + B(x+1)}{x^2-1}$ step leading to your equation between $2x$ and $A$ and $B$.  Sorry if I am being pedantic but I think if the question is relatively easy then you should not assume the questioner can follow multiple transformations per step.

Answer (score 7):

$\dfrac{2x}{x^2-1}dx=\dfrac{d(x^2-1)}{x^2-1}$

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $u=x^2-1$, $\mathrm du=2x\,\mathrm dx$

Then $\int \frac{2x}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm dx=\int \frac{1}{u} \,\mathrm du=\log(u)=\log(x^2-1)$

Answer (score 2):

$\int {2x\over x^2-1}dx
= -\int {2x\over 1-x^2}dx
= -\int 2x dx \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n}
= -2\int dx \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n+1}
= -2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int x^{2n+1}dx
= -2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {x^{2n+2} \over 2n+2}
= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(x^2)^{n+1} \over n+1}
= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(x^2)^{n} \over n}
= \ln(1-x^2)
$.

Check:

$(\ln(1-x^2))'
= {-2x \over 1-x^2}
= {2x \over x^2-1}
$.

Just playing with power series Eulerishly to see what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $$\int(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))}{f(x)}dx=\log(|f(x)|)+C$$
(As seen in $\frac1x dx = \log|x|+C$)

Similarly, $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)=2x$$

$$\therefore\int {2x\over x^2-1}dx=\int(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)}{x^2-1}dx$$

**$$=\log(|x^2-1|)+C$$**

We apply mod in logarithm to take only the positive value of $x^2-1$ because if $x<1$ then $(x^2-1)<0$ and logarithms of negative values do not exist.